# Arranging claws radially and horizontally

Tags: design

I would like to arrange 3 [claws](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87747&name=Barb%20/%20Claw%20/%20Horn%20-%20Large&category=%5BAnimal,%20Body%20Part%5D#T=C&C=89) in a horizontal circle (parallel to the ground ), pointing outward from the circle with roughly equal radial distance (120 degrees) between them.  Any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 6):

Your claws will fit in this Technic element:

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=10288

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert from axle to claw?

Comment: Claws have the usual 3.18mm bar at one end which fits the part mentioned in the answer. So you don't need to convert anything, unless your idea was to attach claws with a pointy end.

Comment: @Alex The round peg fits in the cross-shaped hole? Is that a legal construction?

Comment: Yes, 3.18mm end (peg) fits the inside of Technic connector. That is totally legal  connection. Check 70001 set, for example, which uses both parts mentioned.

Comment: Yes, bars fit nicely in axle holes, its also quite recently (like two years ago) that I learned this.